# How to configure DataGridViewCell to show "3 points button"?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to make a column like this in my `DataGridView` configuring at design time?

[image: "3 points button cell"]

Comment: That looks like a property editor of some sort, not a DGV

Comment: Set the button text to "..."

Comment: The proper term is ellipsis